# Drawing a custom rectangle

Tags: swiftui

I want to make a rectangle with two corner radius in top. but `rectangle()` method doesn't support that.

I also tried `GeometryReader` but doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Hi, you have a sketch of what you want achieve? you need a rectangle with other view inside?

Comment: I need shape like [that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WD4-XeIKKQzkMoQ4Lcy64na9JVZh4iDd/view?usp=sharing) to use as view.

Comment: I posted some code in my answer to create the image you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an example for that in this [article](https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/). The last example does that. The answer is indeed GeometryReader. If you have an issues making it work, post your code here so we can help you.

**UPDATE**

Here's how you would reproduce the image you included in your comments:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {        
        RoundedCorners(color: .black, tl: 35, tr: 35).frame(height: 200)
    }
}

struct RoundedCorners: View {
    var color: Color = .black
    var tl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var tr: CGFloat = 0.0
    var bl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var br: CGFloat = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in

                let w = geometry.size.width
                let h = geometry.size.height

                // We make sure the redius does not exceed the bounds dimensions
                let tr = min(min(self.tr, h/2), w/2)
                let tl = min(min(self.tl, h/2), w/2)
                let bl = min(min(self.bl, h/2), w/2)
                let br = min(min(self.br, h/2), w/2)

                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: w / 2.0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: 0))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: tr), radius: tr, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h - br))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - br, y: h - br), radius: br, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h - bl), radius: bl, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: tl))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: tl, y: tl), radius: tl, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 270), clockwise: false)
            }
            .fill(self.color)
        }
    }
}
```